# Google Analytics Self-Referral Issues

Tags: google-analytics

I am having a self-referral issue in Google Analytics that I cannot seem to solve. Researching the issue, most conclude the main causes are either:

1. Tracking code is missing from certain pages.
2. Incorrect cross-domain or subdomain tracking.

I use an include file with the Universal Analytics code on all pages, so I know missing code cannot be the issue. All user traffic is on a single domain so that cannot be the issue either.

I have also read that sessions expiring can cause self-referrals, but around 80% of referrals are coming from my site so I doubt this is the case.

Here is the tracking code in the include file (not that I think it matters, but I'll include it anyway):

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The only other suggestion I have found is that absolute links could be causing the issue. I am tempted to say this could be the case, as I have noticed the main pages causing self-referrals use absolute links for navigation.

Comment: Let's get to basics here, have you included your domain name in the Referral Exclusion List?

Comment: Yes, I have added my domain (with and without the "www") to the referral exclusion list.